# Why are select events not firing in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios

I have built a [website](http://www.competitionfarm.com/) that uses some simple JavaScript. I make use of many events throughout the website such as the `input` and `submit` event for validating and processing a contact form, the `focus` event for some form-related things and a dynamically-created tab interface, etc. I register all of these handlers using `element.addEventListener("event", handler)`.

My JavaScript works wonderfully everywhere that I have been able to test (Firefox and Chrome on Ubuntu; Firefox and Chrome on Android), except for on iOS devices (regardless of what browser is used), where it seems that very few events are being fired.

It has been difficult for me to debug what the issue is on iOS devices because I do not have an OSX computer to connect an iOS device to so that I can use the remote console. I have come to the conclusion that the events are not firing for a few reasons:

1. The contact form on the website is being submitted even though I make a call to `event.preventDefault()` in the form's `submit` event handler, and do not explicitly submit the form anywhere after that.
2. I have tried catching any errors and displaying them in an alert like so:

   ```
   window.onerror(function(err) { alert(err) })
   ```

   to no avail (i.e. no errors were caught).
3. I have adapted all my functions to make use of only the `click` event, and then they work perfectly!

The last point is a possible solution to the problem, but I think it is bad practice to adapt all my work to one specific platform and rely only on a single event when there are so many purpose-built events that can be used and [that are supposedly supported by iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5) in the first place.

Why are so many events not being fired on iOS devices?

Comment: Can you post some code with a sample event?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually that I had made a `const` declaration in strict mode, which is, [according to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const), not recognized in the current versions of both Safari and iOS Safari (9.1 and 9.3, respectively, as of writing).

I have better documented this problem in [another question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228892/why-is-my-javascript-not-working-correctly-in-strict-mode-on-safari).